# Which one is the fastest: "*" or explicit column names?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find whether using `*` or select only the fields you want is faster. In my case, there will be only one match ever.

So, which is faster? This :

```
SELECT id, name,description,address,phone,img FROM companies WHERE username = '$cname' LIMIT 1
```

or this one?

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE username = '$cname' LIMIT 1
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If there is a difference in those requests it will probably be so minute you don't even notice it. How ever, the second one is my bet

Comment: Unless `*` somehow pulls in *lots of other data*, It Just Doesn't matter. I prefer the former explicit syntax.

Comment: In this case, the difference will be insignificant (if any).

Comment: There should be very minimal time difference between the two. And even if there is, it is not worth your time to look into. Query optimizations are more about how the data is being looked up, combined, etc.

Comment: The one where `$cname="'; DROP TABLE companies; --"` will be slow for the first execution but fast for every one after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr  It Just Doesn't Matter.**

The only case where it would make *any* difference is if there was *lots* of extra data pulled in. The extra overhead needed to be "detectable" *over all the other network/disk/processor factors* will vary: "Try It And See", or, run a performance analysis. Also, even if there were additional columns, since it was limited to one record, it is prudent to remember: **work = effort * quantity**.

I prefer the former explicit syntax myself, except for one-off interactive queries. SQL was meant to be used in a well-shaped manner.

Of course, if the columns in `*` matched the covered columns, then there should be absolutely no difference in terms of performance as they will have the same "shape" and query plans.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, retrieving only the data you need will be faster. I don't believe there's a case where `SELECT *` will be faster for this query. (It's considered bad form anyway.) In many cases, the difference will be miniscule, particularly since you're only retrieving a single row. However, if your table has, say, a BLOB column that isn't one of the named columns, or if it has 50 columns, then the difference might be significant.